# If $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(K)=0$ then $\mathcal{H}^n(K\times \mathbb{R})=0$

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I am reading a paper [Simon and Wickramasekera - A Frequency Function and Singular Set Bounds for Branched Minimal Immersions](https://doi.org/10.1002/cpa.21642) where the authors seem to claim that if $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact set with $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(K)=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure), then $\mathcal{H}^n(K\times \mathbb{R})=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

I want to know how to prove this.

For example, I would be able to prove it if I knew how to prove the following: If $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact set such that $\mathcal{H}^s(K)=0$ ($\mathcal{H}^s$ is the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure) for some $s<n$, then for all $\epsilon>0$ $K$ can be covered by finitely many $B_r(x_i)$, $i=1,...,N$ (same radius) such that $N r^s<\epsilon$.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: What is the paper?

Comment: @LSpice The paper in question is this one from Simon and Wickramasekera https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.21642. In the proof of the theorem contained in the appendix at the end it seems like they are using the result I have stated in the body of my question to get (in their notations) $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(P(\tilde{\Gamma})\times \mathbb{R}^n)=0$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457154/if-mathcalhn-1k-0-in-mathbbrn-then-mathcalhnk-times-mathb#comment1184050_457154), OK, thanks.  I have [edited](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/457154/4) accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for editing (and of course it should be $\mathbb{R}$ not $\mathbb{R}^n$ in my previous comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\de\delta\newcommand\ep\varepsilon\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\N{\mathbb N}$Saúl RM [proved](https://mathoverflow.net/a/457159/36721) the desired result by an application of Frostman's lemma.

Here is an elementary proof:

Take any $\de$ and $\ep$ in $(0,1)$. Then, by the condition $H^{n-1}(K)=0$ and the [definition of the Hausdorff measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure#Definition), there is a set $\{Q_i\colon i\in\N\}$ of closed $n$-cubes in $\R^n$ (that are product sets) such that $\bigcup_{i\in\N}Q_i\supseteq K$, $0<l(Q_i)<\de$ for all $i\in\N$, and
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i\in\N}l(Q_i)^{n-1}<\ep/2, \tag{1}\label{1}   
\end{equation*}
where $l(Q_i)$ is the edge length of the $n$-cube $Q_i$.

For each $i\in\N$, let $N_i:=\lceil 1/l(Q_i)\rceil$, so that
\begin{equation*}
    \frac1{l(Q_i)}\le N_i\le1+\frac1{l(Q_i)}<\frac 2{l(Q_i)}. \tag{2}\label{2}  
\end{equation*}
For each $i\in\N$ and each $j\in[N_i]:=\{1,\dots,N_i\}$, consider the $(n+1)$-cube
\begin{equation*}
    R_{i,j}:=Q_i\times[(j-1)l(Q_i),jl(Q_i)], 
\end{equation*}
with edge length $l(R_{i,j})=l(Q_i)<\de$. Then $\bigcup_{i\in\N}\bigcup_{j\in[N_i]}R_{i,j}\supseteq K\times[0,1]$ and
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i\in\N}\sum_{j\in[N_i]}l(R_{i,j})^n
    =\sum_{i\in\N}\sum_{j\in[N_i]}l(Q_i)^n
    =\sum_{i\in\N}N_i l(Q_i)^n \\ 
    <\sum_{i\in\N}\frac 2{l(Q_i)}l(Q_i)^n
    =2\sum_{i\in\N}l(Q_i)^{n-1}<\ep, 
\end{equation*}
by \eqref{2} and \eqref{1}.

So, again by the definition of the Hausdorff measure,
\begin{equation}
    H^n(K\times[0,1])=0. 
\end{equation}
So/similarly, $H^n(K\times[k,k+1])=0$ for all integers $k$.

So, by the subadditivity of the Hausdorff measure, $H^n(K\times\R)=0$. $\quad\Box$

(The condition that $K$ is compact was not needed or used here.)

Answer (score 5):

[Frostman's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frostman_lemma) seems to work for this problem.

Suppose that $H^n(K\times\mathbb{R})>0$. Then $H^n(K\times[0,1])>0$, so there is a measure $\mu$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with $\mu(K\times[0,1])>0$ and $\mu(B(x,r))\leq r^n$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $r>0$.

Now consider the measure $\nu$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $\nu(A)=\mu(A\times[0,1])$ for Borel sets $A$. Then $\nu(K)>0$, and for any ball $B(x,r)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we can cover the set $B(x,r)\times[0,1]\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by $\frac{N_n}{r}$ balls of radius $r$, where $N_n$ is some big constant dependent only on $n$.

So we have $\nu(B(x,r))\leq\mu(B(x,r)\times[0,1])\leq\frac{N_n}{r}r^n=N_nr^{n-1}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n,r>0$, which by the Frostman lemma implies $H^{n-1}(K)>0$.